# Choosing a pattern for persisting time periods

Tags: postgresql, database-design

In a chat system, I have `users` that can be muted for a specific period of time(eg. 1 hour). For persisting this information I came up with the following two possibilities.

1). I can create a secondary table `muted_users` with the `user_id, muted_at, period` columns, but it seems that I can also add these columns to the `users` table.

2). I can add a `muted_until` column to the `users` table.

Are any of these two patterns correct? If not, what is the correct way of persisting time periods?

Comment: It depends. Would you need to know the muted users history? can a user be muted in one chat room but not in others? we don't really have enough information to provide a definitive answer.

Comment: The `user` entity is muted across all rooms. I query to check if the user is muted only when a message sent by the user is received in the system (so that I do not broadcast it to the other users)

Comment: Well, if you don't need to keep the history of muted users, then go with option 2 - simpler is better.